# Is "should" appropriate for polite requests?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, politeness, register

I am placing request to a customer for a project and I want him to provide some information. I had worked with them in a previous assignment and they failed to provide me most of the details beforehand, so this time I am drafting a mail even before things start out stating my requirements from the customer's side.

Is it good practise to use the word "should"?

For example:

> You should give me A, you should give me  B to proceed with my work.

I for some reason am feeling this is little bit rude.

**P.S.** I know I could phrase my request using *please send me* but there are 15 things actually which I require from them. Would you suggest that I use "Please send" as a prefix to every statement?

Comment: Why haven't they given you A? Are they reluctant? Have they forgotten? Didn't they realise you needed A? Please explain in more detail.

Comment: I had worked with them in a previous assignment and they failed to provide me most of the details beforehand  , so this time I am drafting a mail even before things start out stating my requirements from the customer's side.

Comment: My suggestion, "I am now ready to begin work on your project. Please send me A and I will start work immediately."

Comment: umm... there are 15 things actually which I require from them. Do you suggest me using , "Please Send" as a prefix to every statement?

Comment: I think it's a matter of opinion how best to phrase things. My suggestion is that - particularly given this "client" failed to provide required information promptly in respect of a previous assignment - you should include a section in your email starting with **Please note that I will be unable to proceed with the work until all the following information has been provided...** (italicise ***all*** if you want to make an oblique/snide reference to the previous situation). Then just write a ***numbered checklist*** of all the things you need to know.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I would make that more positive, i.e. "Please note that in order to proceed with the work I need *all* of the following information." --- However, as you say, it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers *To properly proceed with the work, please send me information for **all** of the following:*

Comment: @Noah: I'm afraid not - I dunno what to *call* the grammatical error in your phrasing (it's a bit like a dangling participle), but whatever it is you can't mix the two implied subjects like that (***me*** doing the work, and ***you*** sending the info).

Comment: @FumbleFingers But that's what the OP is trying to do. *Me* doing the work and *you* or *the other person* sending the info. Isn't that the case?

Comment: @Noah: If the "grammatical error" isn't clear to you from my last comment, I think it would be a good idea for you to post a question asking for clarification. Personally, I'd prefer such questions to be asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but I've no doubt it would be properly addressed here on ELU. (And I suppose if ***I*** can't lucidly explain it in a comment, perhaps it's not really just a question for learners/NNS. :)

Comment: Phrase it more as "These are the things I need to have you do so that I can [perform this service]."

Comment: @FumbleFingers (Here)[http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267602/grammatical-error-in-the-following] you go.

Comment: @Noah I think you need to make it clear in the first part of your sentence that it is **you** who will only be able to proceed with the work, once you have received items from your client.  Eg 'Please forward me the following items as soon as possible.  I regret that I am unable to proceed with the project until they are in my possession.'

Comment: Thank you all, I think i will go with @Noah or chasly's interpretation of the content provided by FumbleFinders

Comment: @Noah - I believe what Fumble meant was that your sentence would be clearer like this: *For me to properly proceed with the work, I need you to please send me information for all of the following: -."*  ---  By the way, I agree that the *please* and the *send* should only be used once, and the way to get around this is to use a **bulleted** or **numbered** list.

Answer (score 1):

In general, in English and in other languages, the more words you add the more polite you're being.

Maybe you can say instead,

> Kindly provide...

or

> Could you {please | kindly} provide?