# Grammatical error in the following

Tags: grammar, dangling-participles

I posted a comment to the [Is "should" appropriate for polite requests?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267580/polite-way-of-saying-should?noredirect=1#comment589519_267580) and it was spotted by @FumbleFingers saying that it had a grammatical error. I wonder if someone can elaborate as to where the grammatical error is in the following:

> To properly proceed with the work, please send me information for all of the following

Comment: Oops! I edited that post and modified its title. Sorry! The title is now: **Is “should” appropriate for polite requests?**

Comment: I would replace "To properly" with "So I can".  Also "all" is pretty rude, it implies that unless the sender buckles down and gets everything prepared and sent in one go, it won't be possible to proceed with the work, and it will be their fault.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with your phrasing is that it implies that the person you are addressing, rather than yourself, needs to proceed properly with the work. If you had a sign on your door saying

> To gain access to the office, press the buzzer and wait to be admitted

you would not take that as meaning that somebody else needs to press the buzzer to let you in.

(And thank you for posting here, rather than leaving it to be thrashed out in the comments.)

Comment: +1 particularly for the final parenthetical. But when I suggested Noah should post this as a question, I was kinda hoping someone would give a more "formal" description of the type of error illustrated by the cited example. I think it might be a type of "dangling modifier", but grammatical terminology isn't my strong suit.

Comment: Isn't this just a shorter way of saying: "In order to proceed properly..."? If the OP wants to refer to himself then: *"In order for me to proceed properly..."*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Have done my best :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Exactly so, for the reasons stated below :)

Answer (score 5):

> > To properly proceed with the work, please send me information for all of the following.

The verb *send* is part of an imperative construction and uses the plain form of the verb without an expressed Subject. However, there is still an unexpressed Subject that we can reconstruct: it is *you*, in other words the people being addressed by the speaker.

When we use an infinitive of purpose as an Adjunct in the clause structure, like the one in the Original Poster's example, we do not have to reiterate the Subject *if it is the same* as the Subject of the main clause:

- To annoy the crocodile, the chicken crossed the road.

Here because the chicken is the Subject of the main clause, we do not need to expressly stipulate the Subject of the infinitival clause. Indeed to do so would be rather odd:

- ?For the chicken to annoy the crocodile, the chicken crossed the road
- ?In order for the chicken to annoy the crocodile, the chicken crossed the road.

Because the speaker intends the Subject of the infinitival clause to be himself, he needs to stipulate the Subject. This is because it is not the same Subject as the unexpressed Subject of the main clause:

- For me to properly proceed with the work, please send me information for all of the following.
- In order for me to properly proceed with the work, please send me information for all of the following.

If we don't stipulate the Subject of the infinitival clause, the natural reading is that the  Subject of *proceed with the work* is the same as the notional Subject of *send*. In other words we are likely to understand it as:

- For you to properly proceed with the work, please (you) send me information for all of the following.
- In order for you to properly proceed with the work, please (you) send me information for all of the following.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you are saying that the sentence should be "In order for me to..." because there is a confusion with the subject of the sentence.

Comment: @michael_timofeev Yes, that's right. It could be either *For me to...* or *In order for me to ...*. Both are fine. If we don't use one of those, the listener will understand the wrong subject for the infinitival clause. :)

Comment: so why is it that the original sentence seems ok to me?

Comment: @michael_timofeev It's just because there is no context there. So I'm guessing that you understood the OP's sentence to mean "In order for you to be able to precede, could you send the information". That's a perfectly normal reading of the OP's sentence. It's just that that's not what OP wanted to say.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: *"For you to proceed properly"* ? The speaker wants to the work to begin in an orderly fashion which will continue throughout its duration. To *properly proceed* implies only the initial stage. Does it make any difference? Is it just me?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think that the duration thingie is only an implication when the *properly* comes after the verb. (That doesn't mean it isn't there though!) However, I'd say that your formulation sounds more natural altogether. The OP's is grammatical, but a bit marked. It does sound a wee bit awkward. (in my opinion)

Comment: *To upvote this answer, answer one minor question*. Are you actually saying that's "grammatical" (just a bit "marked")? I assume you can understand what I *mean* - but just in case, I'll paraphrase as ***I'm** withholding my upvote until **you** answer this question*. And to be honest I probably *won't* upvote if your answer nets down to ***Yes*** because I *don't* think it's grammatically valid. Unless we accept the creative use of *to upvote* to mean *to **cause to be** upvoted [by someone else, which might not even be me]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think it can be used to mean what the OP wants it to mean. But it's grammatical in the sense that *it means something else* in a perfectly grammatical way. So a parallel example would be *to be in the shade, put them under a tree*. So that can't mean *for them to be in the shade, put them under a tree*, but if you mean *for you to be in the shade, put them under a tree* that would be ok. (For example - it's something you might say if putting *them*  under a tree also reserved you a space under a tree. But I don't know how we could say that it was *ungrammatical* ...

Comment: @FumbleFingers  ... as such. It kind of just means something else. It's kind of an odd thing to say that a putatively grammatical sentence which would mean something different from what it's intended to mean is ungrammatical. But I suppose it might be. It's just a weird idea in relation to the phrase *grammatical* ....

Comment: Ah, right. I see what you mean now. And I agree. You're quite right, of course - the construction itself is grammatical, and once I force myself to discard the (superficially obvious) meaning *OP* intended, I can easily imagine a (somewhat contrived) context where the cited text validly expresses something like *[In order for **you**] to properly proceed with/progress the work, please [do this]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I suppose we might still be able to say that the OP's example includes a grammatical mistake though? Which is what I think we're both thrusting at. (i.e. it involves a misunderstanding about what the grammar is actually doing)

Comment: Syntactically the sentence is fine, but the semantics are flawed. Whether "grammatical", in a general meaning, includes semantics, I do not know.

Comment: @msam's approach looks good to me. As I understand it, *syntax* is a subset of *grammar*, which is all about whether the structure (and/or morphology, etc.) of an utterance is allowed by "the rules". So what we have is an utterance that's *grammatical* ("valid", if one restricts oneself to that context), but which is *semantically* "invalid" in OP's specific case because *it doesn't **mean** what the speaker wants to say*.